How to combine two columns into `{key:value}` pairs in polars?
I'm working with a Polars DataFrame, and I want to combine two columns into a dictionary format, where the values from one column become the keys and the values from the other column become the corresponding values.
Here's an example DataFrame:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["Chuck", "John", "Alice"],
    "surname": ["Dalliston", "Doe", "Smith"]
})

I want to transform this DataFrame into a new column that contains dictionaries, where name is the key and surname is the value. The expected outcome should look like this:
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ name  │ surname │ name_surname             │
│ ---   │ ---     │ ---                      │
│ str   │ str     │ dict[str, str]           │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ Chuck │ Dalliston│ {"Chuck": "Dalliston"}   │
│ John  │ Doe     │ {"John": "Doe"}          │
│ Alice │ Smith   │ {"Alice": "Smith"}       │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────┘

I've tried the following code:
df.with_columns(
    json = pl.struct("name", "surname").map_elements(json.dumps)
)

But the result is not as expected. Instead of creating a dictionary with key-value, it produces:
{name:Chuck,surname:Dalliston}


Polars does not have a native dict type https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/datatypes.html. You could store a python dict as a pl.Object but whether that's a good idea depends on how you want to use the column after creating it.

The new column is then saved in jsonb field in postgres db

You can try this code snippet, This seems to be the closest you can get has pl does not have a naive dict.
See reference : data_types_polaris
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"name": ["Chuck", "John", "Alice"], "surname": ["Dalliston", "Doe", "Smith"]}
)

df = df.select(
    [
        "name",
        "surname",
        (
            pl.struct(["name", "surname"]).map_elements(
                lambda row: {row["name"]: row["surname"]}, return_dtype=pl.Object
            )
        ).alias("name_surname"),
    ]
)
print(df)

┌───────┬───────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ name  ┆ surname   ┆ name_surname           │
│ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---                    │
│ str   ┆ str       ┆ object                 │
╞═══════╪═══════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ Chuck ┆ Dalliston ┆ {'Chuck': 'Dalliston'} │
│ John  ┆ Doe       ┆ {'John': 'Doe'}        │
│ Alice ┆ Smith     ┆ {'Alice': 'Smith'}     │
└───────┴───────────┴────────────────────────┘


import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"name": ["Chuck", "John", "Alice"], "surname": ["Dalliston", "Doe", "Smith"]}
)
df = df.with_columns(
            json=pl.concat_str(
                pl.lit("{"),
                pl.col("specification_name"),
                pl.lit(":"),
                pl.col("specification_value"),
                pl.lit("}"),
                separator='"',
            )
        )

This will return a json as string
